# How to find the continous range of dates in Sql Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do we find the continous range of dates from the following scenario?

```
    Id  modifiedDate  StartDate   EndDate
    1   2019-01-01    2019-01-01  2019-12-31
    1   2019-02-02    2019-02-01  2019-02-28
    1   2019-02-27    2019-01-15  2019-03-15
    1   2019-03-01    2019-03-01  2019-03-12
    2   2019-01-01    2019-01-01  2019-03-01
    2   2019-05-01    2019-05-01  2019-08-01

The Output i want to show is :

       Id  StartDate    EndDate
       1   2019-01-01   2019-01-15
       1   2019-01-15   2019-02-01
       1   2019-02-01   2019-02-28
       1   2019-02-28   2019-03-01
       1   2019-03-01   2019-03-12
       2   2019-01-01   2019-03-01
       2   2019-05-01   2019-08-01
```

What I have tried so far is :

```
With X As(
Select a.StartDate,a.EndDate,b.StartDate,b.EndDate
From table a Full Join table b ON a.endDate>b.StartDate
Where a.StartDate<>b.StartDate and b.endDate<>a.Enddate
)
Select StartDate,Enddate,Min(StartDtae)
From X
Group By StartDate,EndDate
```

But I couldn't get fill the gaps in between the dates. How can I fix this?

Comment: It looks like you want to union the start dates onto the end dates, sort them then take each row's date as the start date and each row+1's date as the end date, am i right?

Comment: on your row number 4 there is a date '2019-03-15', it is no where in your result...? same on very first row with '2019-12-01'

Comment: MySQL? Oracle? Or MSSQL?

Answer (score 3):

You can try this following script I have created with the Help of CTE and Row_Number(). I am getting 2 additional row considering your sample output from the the given input data. If you sample output is correct, you can ignore this solution.

> CTE Only worked for MSSQL and Oracle. But you can convert the logic given, for any other databases.

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT id,Date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY Date) RN
    FROM
    (
        SELECT Id,StartDate Date FROM your_table
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Id,EndDate  FROM your_table
    ) A
)

SELECT A.Id, A.Date StartDate,B.Date EndDate 
FROM CTE A
INNER JOIN CTE B ON A.Id = B.Id AND A.RN = B.RN - 1
```

Output is-

```
Id  StartDate   EndDate
1   2019-01-01  2019-01-15
1   2019-01-15  2019-02-01
1   2019-02-01  2019-02-28
1   2019-02-28  2019-03-01
1   2019-03-01  2019-03-12
1   2019-03-12  2019-03-15 -- Not exist in your expected output
1   2019-03-15  2019-12-31 -- Not exist in your expected output
```

**Note**: Adding an additional Filtering at the as below will give you the exact output you have posted. But take your own decision which one best suits your requirement.

```
SELECT....
....
FROM CTE A
INNER JOIN CTE B ON A.Id = B.Id AND A.RN = B.RN - 1
WHERE B.DATE <= '2019-03-12'
```

Comment: Perfect!! You can add simple `WHERE` condition to ignore unexpected rows.

Comment: @Tejash----ORA-00980 thanks. Can you explain a bit more regarding WHERE?

Comment: `SELECT A.Id, A.Date StartDate,B.Date EndDate 
FROM CTE A
INNER JOIN CTE B ON A.Id = B.Id AND A.RN = B.RN WHERE B.DATE <= DATE '2019-03-12`

Comment: Just to make it as expected output. But your logic is perfect.

Comment: Sorry as I can not understand :( Please tell me the full condition. that will help :)

Comment: Got your point. But using  WHERE B.DATE <=  '2019-03-12' will make the script static I guess. Should I apply that?

Comment: Added suggestion for OP.

Comment: To make it complex i added one more scenario. for the Id 2 we are getting the 3 rows if we follow the your logic

Comment: @Naveen132 can you please check the alternate option I have added at the end of my answer? hopefully this will serve your purpose.

Comment: When you put a condition ON A.StartDate=B.StartDate this actually display the previous values i think. pl correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Can you please post how the output will be?

Comment: we can solve it in one way, We can populate a new column(GapDate), if the next startDate>Current EndDate then we can keep the startDate value in GapDate Column. And then we can join the populated result and base table with A.EndDate!=B.StartDate and A.GapDate!=B.EndDate

Comment: I will check the possibilities shortly.

Answer (score 0):

The following query should give you the desired result:

```
WITH dates AS (SELECT StartDate
                 FROM TABLE
                UNION
               SELECT EndDate + 1
                 FROM TABLE)
SELECT StartDate 
     , (SELECT MIN(StartDate) - 1
          FROM dates b
         WHERE StartDate - 1 > a.StartDate) EndDate
  FROM dates a
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `lead()` with `union`:

```
select t.id, t.dte as startdate,
       lead(t.dte) over (partition by t.id order by t.dte) as enddate
from (select distinct t.id, v.dte
      from t cross apply
           (values (startdate), (enddate)) v(dte)
     ) t;
```

In addition to being concise, this probably has the best performance.

Comment: To make it complex i added one more scenario. for the Id 2 we are getting the 3 rows if we follow the your logic