# find the continuous range of dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do we find the continuous range of dates from the following scenario?

```
Id  modifiedDate  StartDate   EndDate
1   2019-01-01    2019-01-01  2019-12-31
1   2019-02-02    2019-02-01  2019-02-28
1   2019-02-27    2019-01-15  2019-03-15
1   2019-03-01    2019-03-01  2019-03-12
2   2019-01-01    2019-01-01  2019-03-01
2   2019-05-01    2019-05-01  2019-08-01
```

The output I want to show is:

```
   Id  StartDate    EndDate
   1   2019-01-01   2019-01-15
   1   2019-01-15   2019-02-01
   1   2019-02-01   2019-02-28
   1   2019-02-28   2019-03-01
   1   2019-03-01   2019-03-12
   1   2019-03-12   2019-03-15
   1   2019-03-15   2019-12-31
   2   2019-01-01   2019-03-01
   2   2019-05-01   2019-08-01
```

What I have tried so far is:

```
With X As(
  Select a.StartDate,a.EndDate,b.StartDate,b.EndDate
  From table a Full Join table b ON a.endDate>b.StartDate
  Where a.StartDate<>b.StartDate and b.endDate<>a.Enddate
)
Select StartDate,Enddate,Min(StartDtae)
From X
Group By StartDate,EndDate
```

For the first one I can do union and fix, but for the second id I cannot follow the union process to show the desired output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the continous range of dates in Sql Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57388633/how-to-find-the-continous-range-of-dates-in-sql-server)

Comment: why first row of id 2 has end date '2019-03-01' but not considered as startdate in next row?

Comment: because the id 2 is not valid between 3 and 5 months

Comment: and how it is validating to exclude this..?

Comment: we do not have anything other than these columns. we just have to check the dates

Answer (score 0):

You may try this.

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT id,Date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY Date) RN
    FROM
    (
        SELECT Id,StartDate Date FROM your_table
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Id,EndDate  FROM your_table
    ) A
)

SELECT A.Id, A.Date StartDate,B.Date EndDate 
FROM CTE A
INNER JOIN CTE B ON A.Id = B.Id AND A.RN = B.RN - 1
```

Comment: This logic will not satisfy the Id 2
The output i get if i try this for id 2 is 3 rows, but id 2 is invalid in between 2019-03-01 to 2019-05-01

Comment: @Naveen132: in your previous question, i'll ask for same what happen to the endDate of first row. i,e; '2019-12-31', where is this date in your ouput?